# how dynamically read image file shiny R

Tags: html, r, shiny

I'm downloading a png image according to user provided input, and I show the image with

```
mainPanel(
    img(src="file.png", height =1187 , width = 748)
)
```

but, if the user changes the input I have to refresh the page.

The app draft is follows below

the ui

```
library(shiny)
org <- read.delim("http://rest.kegg.jp/list/organism", header=FALSE) 
org <- apply(org[,2:3], 1, function(x)  paste(as.matrix(x), collapse="-"))

# Define UI for dataset viewer application
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Reactivity"),

  # Sidebar with controls to provide a caption, select a dataset, and 
  # specify the number of observations to view. Note that changes made
  # to the caption in the textInput control are updated in the output
  # area immediately as you type
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("caption", "Caption:", "Data Summary"),
 tags$textarea(id="foo", rows=3, cols=40, "Default value"), 
      selectInput("dataset", "Choose an organism:", 
              choices = org ),

      numericInput("obs", "Number of observations to view:", 10)
        ),


    # Show the caption, a summary of the dataset and an HTML table with
    # the requested number of observations
    mainPanel(
      h3(textOutput("caption")), 

      verbatimTextOutput("summary"), 

          tableOutput("view"),
    plotOutput('plot1'),
   img(src="file.png", height =1187 , width = 748)

    )
  )
))
```

and the server

```
library(shiny)

    # Define server logic required to summarize and view the selected dataset
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

       output$caption <- renderText({
        cps <- strsplit(input$foo, "\\s+")[[1]]

        #tab <- read.table("http://rest.kegg.jp/link/pathway/zma")
        #path2cpd <- read.table("http://rest.kegg.jp/link/pathway/compound")  
        #allmetab <- unique(path2cpd[which(path2cpd[,2] %in% sub("path:zma", "path:map", tab[,2])),]) 
        #cps <- unique(allmetab[,1])
        #
        url <- "http://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/show_pathway?zma00944+default%3dred+"
        url <- paste(url, paste(cps, collapse="+"), sep="+")

        download.file(url, "form.html")
        lines <- readLines("form.html")
        imgUrl <- lines[grep('img src="/', lines)]
        url <- paste0("http://www.kegg.jp/", strsplit(imgUrl, '"')[[1]][2])
        download.file(url, "www/file.png")
        url

      })

      # The output$summary depends on the datasetInput reactive expression, 
      # so will be re-executed whenever datasetInput is invalidated
      # (i.e. whenever the input$dataset changes)

     output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      })


    })
```

if you paste the compound codes

```
C01477
C04608
C04858
C05622
```

in the box with "Default Value" written I would like to automatically update the picture, or at least have a button to update without having to reload all the app.

If one reloads the navigator one can see the figure with the red dots colored (at the page bottom).

How can I make the function read the image again after a time interval?

Comment: So you are keeping the file name the same, just updating the file contents?

Comment: what is the input you are talking about ? it would be clearer with a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Hi MrFlick an Stéphane, yes the file name is the same, and the example follows above. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I don't understand your app and we don't know yet what your code looks like.

Comment: Hi Stéphane, I'm sorry, I'm far from being a good programmer, I will post the code, the app is not finished, I just want to this feature of image reloading...